# get values from JSON in QT

Tags: json, algorithm, qt

I have a QJSonDocument like this:

```
QJsonDocument([{"name":"name1", "status":true}, {"name":"name2", "status":true}{"name":"name3", "status":true}])
```

And I want to get all the names and save them in a QList
Thanks

have no Idea where to start

Edit:

here's the code that I got

```
void MainWindow::loadNames()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("http://test:3030/names"));
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(req);

    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, [ reply](){
        auto json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());

        QList<QString> *names = new QList<QString>;

    });
}
```

I want to know how I can get only the names from the JSON and put it in the QList.

Comment: Where exactly did you get stuck while parsing the QJSonDocument (or using a already existing parser). Please add your code and a specific problem description.

Comment: I edited the post and added more info hope it helps

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (did not checked) should do the job:

```
QList<QString> names;
const QJsonArray jsonArray = json.toArray();
for(const QJsonValue& value : jsonArray) {
        QJsonObject json = value.toObject();
        if (json.contains("name") && json["name"].isString())
            names.append(json["name"].toString().trimmed());
}
```